# Is it free to use the AWS Query API to get the prices of a service programmtically?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using the [AWS Price List Query API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/using-pelong.html) to get only pricing for EC2 and EBS services.

Is it free to use the AWS Price List API?

Do I also need to create a new client for every pricing call?

Below is the code that I use:

```
AWSPricing pricing_client = AWSPricingClientBuilder.standard()
.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("mycredentials")))
.withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
.build();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it free to use the AWS Price List API?

**Yes, using the AWS Price List API is free of charge.**

Other paid APIs like the AWS Cost Explorer API mention [pricing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-what-is.html) & have been listed on [AWS Cost Management Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/pricing/) as having a cost associated with them.

The Price List API is not on the pricing page, nor has a cost mentioned anywhere in the documentation so it is safe to assume that it is free (after all, you're just getting AWS's pricing data).

> Do I also need to create a new client for every pricing call?

**No, it isn't needed nor recommended.**

Use the same pricing client for as many calls as needed.

Comment: Many thanks, a big  confusion has been resolved. Thanks a lot for such a precise, straightforward and to the point answer. Thanks again

Comment: No worries, you're very welcome @WaleedAsif :)

Comment: @WaleedAsif please accept the answer if it helped you or at least upvote it.